# LoopBack operation hook use multiple models

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs

I've got a question about LoopBack's operation hooks.

With help of what is said [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Operation-hooks.html#after-save), I'm trying to create a **Privilege** object programmatically whenever the 'after save' event of my **Company** model is triggered. This is to have automatically objects created after one is being saved.

> Please note that I've simplified my case to make it simple but I will actually create several objects after the creation of a **Company**.

I have created a script int my `common/models/` folder which contains the following code:

```
module.exports = function (Company) {
    Company.observe('after save', function createObjectsForNewClient(ctx, next) {
    if (ctx.instance) {
        log('A new Company has been created. Shall create a Privilege for it.');

        Privilege.create(
            {...},
            function (err, obj) {
                if(err)
                    console.error(err);

                if(obj)
                    console.lof(obj);
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

With this, the hook is triggered correctly but LoopBack stops with an exception saying:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Privilege' of undefined

I thought this model would be available from somewhere in some loopback/javascript/almost-magic scope. The thing is that I've also tried adding the **Privilege** model in the `module.exports = function (Company, Privilege) {...` block but it does not seem to accept listing an infinite number of models to be used in the function...
You should also note that I've created my models into JSON files in the `common/models/` folder but no other JS scripts for those models because LoopBack seems to handle the export automatically. Would it have an impact on the fact that they are not accessible as I want ?

I might have done something wrong somewhere but what I'm trying to do seemed fairly simple. Does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other models are accesible via `Model.app.models`.

I usually define all the models my remote method or hook requires in the first few lines, for example:

```
module.exports = function (Company) {
    Company.observe('after save', function createObjectsForNewClient(ctx, next) {
        const Privilege = Company.app.models.Privilege,
              OtherModel = Company.app.models.OtherModel;
        // the rest of your operation hook
```

Note that you have to do this for every method. This won't work because models are not bootstrapped at compilation time:

```
module.exports = function (Company) {
    // won't work
    const OtherModel = Company.app.models.OtherModel;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed. Also thank you for the tip, I would have probably lost time trying to make my code generic by globalizing my other models!